# How to use CSS with Windows 8 Webview Control?

Tags: html, c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a question about window's 8 apps Webview Control , is there anyway to use css to manage the look of the webview , i'm using it here to view a returned contents of a feeded html data but as you can see it's striped from all the CSS , so is there anyway that I can manage the CSS for the Webview ?

UPATED : This is the code

```
void ItemListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {


            //  this code to populate the web view
            //  with the content of the selected blog post.
            // I'm passing the selected item from the previous items' page
            // and then pouplate the web view with the selected item Contents of the feed 


            if (this.UsingLogicalPageNavigation()) this.InvalidateVisualState();

            Selector list = sender as Selector;
            FeedItem selectedItem = list.SelectedItem as FeedItem;
            if (selectedItem != null)
            {
                this.contentView.NavigateToString(selectedItem.Contents);
            }
            else
            {
                this.contentView.NavigateToString("");
            }  

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate with NavigateToString() - you can put your css inside of the html string that you navigate to. Otherwise - it should just work and we would need more details for what you are actually doing.

Comment: You can embed the style in the html `<head/>` element like `<style TYPE="text/css">`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3

Comment: Sir I know how to embed the style of css in html page , i'm asking here how to embed it to the Webview control ?

Comment: Well, your selectedItem.Contents is an html string, right? If you want to use css with it - you need to embed the style in that html string. I don't believe there is a way to supply it separately.

Comment: Ummm, I think I got what you mean let me try that and see what I will come up with , thank you very much for your help .